# What is the difference between class alv and function alv

Tags: abap, alv

We are using class alv and function alv, what is the difference between those options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Some of the differences:

  - You can create screens using  function modules however classes have to call separate program to generate screens.
  - Classes are more secure than FMs.
  - Class type increases the performance.
  - Class type is OO, it allows more flexibility. Can have multiple ALVs in one screen.
  - Classes will allow reusability better than FM because being Object Oriented.
  - Classes are instantiable while function groups are not.
  - Objects are the instance of class but FMs are not instances of a Function Group.
  - Function modules can be executed asynchronously and can be called by other systems remotely also.
  - A program can work with instances of several function groups at the same time however it cannot work with several instances of a single function group.

*This [referance](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/c3/225b5954f411d194a60000e8353423/content.htm) could be helpful too.

Hope it was helpful

Talha

Comment: This is very useful answer, thanks. I have another question too actually, how can i understand is the code written with functions or with class? Is there an obvious difference between the code writing? Like, is there a class definition into class alv's code?

Comment: Those are written in code differently, for functions you can use REUSE_ALV_* methods and for Classes it would be like "CL_SALV_TABLE", get this [link](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+-+Developing+Interactive+ALV+Report+using+OOABAP) as an example for OO SALV Classes. [HERE IS AN EXAMPLE](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ALV+grid+control+with+2+different+approaches%21) for ALV grid control with 2 different approaches. Hope its helpful.